# How to Auto populate account name

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm stuck and want a way to solve a problem . The requirement is when i click on custom button it should redirect me to the Contact page WITH auto populate Account field. I've reach with the redirect and stucked with auto populate . How do i do it ? Thanks in advance. Any modifications with my code would be helpful.

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="NewContact">
  <apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock title="New Contact " mode="edit">
 <apex:pageBlockButtons >
    <apex:commandButton action="{!Cancel}" value="Cancel"/>
  </apex:pageBlockButtons>

<apex:pageBlockSection title="Contact Details" columns="2">
  <apex:CommandButton action="{!NewImplementation}" value="New Implementation" />
</apex:pageblocksection>
```

```
  == Class==


  public class NewContact {

   public NewContact(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
   }
   public PageReference NewImplementation() {
     PageReference secondPage = new PageReference ('/003/e');
     secondPage.setRedirect(true);        
     return secondPage; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you want this button to appear?

Comment: I've already created a button and clicking on it , it is redirecting me to Contact page . Now the issue is , Account Name field should be auto populated when i click on the same button.

Comment: You are not answering my question. Where do you want this button to appear? On Account detail page?

Comment: Button is simply displayed on a custom Vf page. I do not want the button to appear. For button i've made custom vf page.

Answer (score 1):

To pre-populate a field you can use some url parameters. The process is described in this blog article:

http://simplysfdc.blogspot.de/2012/11/custom-button-to-prepulate-field.html

There is also a youtube video which explains the process:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_WHpTOF3bFo

**Suggestion**

In your case you have to add 2 parameters to the PageReference url. like

PageReference secondPage = new PageReference `('/003/e?MYFIELDID_lkid=ACCOUNT_RECORD_ID&MYFIELD_ID=ACCOUNT_Name');`

Replace `MYFIELDID`with the account field ID. The `ACCOUNT_RECORD_ID` with your account ID and `ACCOUNT_NAME` with the account name.

Comment: It will be helpful if you can help me with any additions with my code. Pressing my head.

Comment: @JJoseph - The answer given already does what you ask...We do not write code for you rather we provide you with the means to understand how to do it and update your own code. If you do not understand the answer please clarify where you are having difficulty